# Delete Multiple lines in consecutive pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have below string(Captured by Drone GPS).

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,033
<font size="36">FrameCnt : 1, DiffTime : 33ms
2022-10-08 10:39:34,664,324
[iso : 100] [shutter : 1/1000.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : -0.7] [ct : 4878] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.726788] [longtitude : 76.246599] [altitude: 334.510010] </font>

2
00:00:00,033 --> 00:00:00,066
<font size="36">FrameCnt : 2, DiffTime : 33ms
2022-10-08 10:39:34,697,694
[iso : 100] [shutter : 1/1000.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : -0.7] [ct : 4878] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.726788] [longtitude : 76.246599] [altitude: 334.510010] </font>

3
00:00:00,066 --> 00:00:00,100
<font size="36">FrameCnt : 3, DiffTime : 34ms
2022-10-08 10:39:34,731,055
[iso : 100] [shutter : 1/1000.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : -0.7] [ct : 4878] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.726788] [longtitude : 76.246599] [altitude: 334.510010] </font>

4
00:00:00,100 --> 00:00:00,133
<font size="36">FrameCnt : 4, DiffTime : 33ms
2022-10-08 10:39:34,764,424
[iso : 100] [shutter : 1/1000.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : -0.7] [ct : 4878] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.726788] [longtitude : 76.246599] [altitude: 334.537994] </font>

5
00:00:00,133 --> 00:00:00,166
<font size="36">FrameCnt : 5, DiffTime : 33ms
2022-10-08 10:39:34,797,792
[iso : 100] [shutter : 1/1000.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : -0.7] [ct : 4878] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.726788] [longtitude : 76.246599] [altitude: 334.537994] </font>
```

I want to delete all lines containing "Date and Time"
I want output as per below.

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:00,033
<font size="36">FrameCnt : 1, DiffTime : 33ms
[iso : 100] [shutter : 1/1000.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : -0.7] [ct : 4878] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.726788] [longtitude : 76.246599] [altitude: 334.510010] </font>

2
00:00:00,033 --> 00:00:00,066
<font size="36">FrameCnt : 2, DiffTime : 33ms
[iso : 100] [shutter : 1/1000.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : -0.7] [ct : 4878] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.726788] [longtitude : 76.246599] [altitude: 334.510010] </font>

3
00:00:00,066 --> 00:00:00,100
<font size="36">FrameCnt : 3, DiffTime : 34ms
[iso : 100] [shutter : 1/1000.0] [fnum : 280] [ev : -0.7] [ct : 4878] [color_md : default] [focal_len : 280] [latitude : 25.726788] [longtitude : 76.246599] [altitude: 334.510010] </font
```

These lines are in specific patterns
Line Numbers (**4,10,16,22,28,...**)

I have tried this but problem is in every new files I have to put date manually.

```
.*2022-09-29.*[\r]?[\n]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\h.*\R
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d` Match the date like pattern where `\d` matches a digit
- `\h` Match a horizontal whitespace char
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `\R` Match a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eytJHn/1)

In the replacement use an empty string.

Comment: This is a good one. One question: `\R` is to match a new line so `\n` doesn't work here? Sorry if its a dummy question, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hi there, `\n` or as the OP has it as `\r?\n` will also work. Using `\R` matches any unicode newline sequence.